# Refactor Laravel Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have a query that I have built, and I am trying to understand how I can achieve the same thing but in one single query. I am fairly new to Laravel and learning. Anyway someone could help me understand how I can achieve what I am after?

```php
$activePlayerRoster = array();

$pickupGames = DB::table('pickup_games')
  ->where('pickupDate', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('m/d/Y'))
  ->orderBy('pickupDate', 'ASC')
  ->get();

foreach ($pickupGames as $games) {

  foreach(DB::table('pickup_results')
            ->where('pickupRecordLocatorID', $games->recordLocatorID)
            ->get() as $activePlayers) {

    $activePlayerRoster[] = $activePlayers->playerID;
    $unique = array_unique($activePlayerRoster);

  }

}

$activePlayerList = array();

foreach($unique as $playerID) {

  $playerinfo = DB::table('players')
                  ->select('player_name')
                  ->where('player_id', $playerID)
                  ->first();
  $activePlayerList[] = $playerinfo;

}

return $activePlayerList;
```

`pickup_games`
checkSumID
pickupDate
startTime
endTime
gameDuration
winningTeam
recordLocatorID
pickupID

1546329808471
01/01/2019
08:03 am
08:53 am
50 Minute
2
f47ac0fc775cb5793-0a8a0-ad4789d4
216

`pickup_results`

id
checkSumID
playerID
team
gameResult
pickOrder
pickupRecordLocatorID

1
1535074728532
425336395712954388
1
Loss
0
be3532dbb7fee8bde-2213c-5c5ce710

Comment: Do you have any relationships set up with your models?

Comment: no i do not have any relationships setup.

Comment: I don't feel like there'd be a simple way of achieving this with a simple query, but I am also curious to know :)

Comment: each table is interconnected with unique data elements if thats what youre referring too. @Mozammil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should try to write SQL query, and then convert it to Laravel's database code.

If performance is not critical for you, then it could be done in one query like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT players.player_name FROM pickup_results
LEFT JOIN players ON players.player_id = pickup_results.playerID
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM pickup_games
  WHERE pickupDate >= DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), '%m/%d/%Y')
    AND pickup_results.pickupRecordLocatorID = recordLocatorID
)
```

Here I'm assuming you know what you're doing with this dates comparison, because it looks weird to me.

Now, let's convert it to Laravel's code:

```php
DB::table('pickup_results')
  ->select('players.player_name')->distinct()
  ->leftJoin('players', 'players.player_id', '=', 'pickup_results.playerID')
  ->whereExists(function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
          ->from('pickup_games')
          ->where('pickupDate', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('m/d/Y'))
          ->whereRaw('pickup_results.pickupRecordLocatorID = recordLocatorID'); 
  })
  ->get();
```

Comment: Wonderful. Only problem ive noticed is it doesnt pull all players that have played in the past 30 days. I've verified a few users have played, yet doesnt return as such. Ideas? @Styx

Comment: @Kray Told you your dates comparison seems weird :) Could you show a couple of rows from your DB with dates? Better yet — start a new question about that.

Comment: I added the tables in OP.

Comment: @Kray Better start new question about comparison of dates with non-standard format, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: im not sure what to ask, and not sure it warrants a new question?

Comment: @Kray This current question is about refactoring SQL query. Now, you have another problem: dates comparison. Regardless of link to this question, this new problem should be asked in new question. I could say upfront that your issue is with format you're storing you dates in. For example, `"02/10/2019" >= "30/01/2019"` will be `false`, and that's wrong.

Comment: The way I am storing them is m/d/Y @Styx

Comment: What should it be? @Styx

Comment: @Kray It should be `Y-m-d` or just `DATE` field type

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I would reduce the query to its SQL variant to get directly at its core.
The essence of the query is

```
select `x` FROM foo WHERE id IN (
  select distinct bar.id from bar join baz on bar.id = baz.id);
```

This can be interpreted in Eloquent as:

```
$thirtyDaysAgo = Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('m/d/Y');

$playerIds = DB::table('pickup_games')
  ->select('pickup_games.player_id')
  ->join(
      'pickup_results',
      'pickup_results.pickupRecordLocatorID',
      'pickup_games.recordLocatorID')
  ->where('pickupDate', '>=', $thirtyDaysAgo)
  ->orderBy('pickupDate', 'ASC')
  ->distinct('pickup_games.player_id');


$activePlayers = DB::table('players')
      ->select('player_name')
      ->whereIn('player_id', $playerIds);

//>>>$activePlayers->toSql();
//select "player_name" from "players" where "player_id" in (
//  select distinct * from "pickup_games" 
//  inner join "pickup_results" 
//    on "pickup_results"."pickupRecordLocatorID" = "pickup_games"."recordLocatorID" 
//  where "pickupDate" >= ? order by "pickupDate" asc
//)
```

From the resulting query, it may be better to refactor the join as relationship between the Eloquent model for `pickup_games` and `pickup_results`. This will help to further simplify `$playerIds`.